# Closing HTML tag

Tags: html, xhtml

When is it appropriate to use a closing tag and when a slash is enough?

```
<div></div>
```

vs.

```
<div />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Comment: That slash is a XHTML thing. XHTML is a failed concept, so don't use it. Empty elements consist of only one tag (e.g. `<input type="text">`), whereas non-empty elements have a start tag and an end tag (e.g. `<div> content </div>`).

Comment: If you want to know which elements are empty and which are non-empty, look up the element [in the standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/#auto-toc-4) and inspect its **Content model**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use a self closing tag `<div />` if your DOCTYPE is set to XHTML as this is borrowed from XML where you can have self closing tags. You can't have it if your DOCTYPE is set to HTML 4.01 or HTML 5.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/

I'm not sure your exact use case for wanting this, but if it's for clearing floats, you can do this instead and not have to worry about compatibility issues, especially with IE if it kicks into emulation mode.

```
<style type="text/css">
.clear-fix {
    clear: both !important;
    display: block !important;
    font-size: 0 !important;
    line-height: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    list-style: none !important;
}
</style>
<br class="clear-fix" />
```

Comment: I think you nailed it in the first 2 sentences, but lost me in the rest of the post. A little overkill with "!important", hah? IE is a pain but I think it can be fixed with proper DOCTYPE tag. :) +1

Comment: @Patrick Sure you can. You can have a `<br />` element inside a HTML 4 or HTML5 document, and you can have a `<br>` element inside a XHTML document. The browsers **don't care**!

Comment: This is a perfect use case for the `!important` tag. With `clear-fix` being a class, it's at the bottom of ranking when it comes to things that can overwrite it's values. These states should **ALWAYS** be true no matter what when you're clearing a float.

Comment: @Šime You can't place a `<br>` inside a XHTML document and validate against W3C standards.

Answer (score 4):

Closing tag is needed for elements that (can) contain something, such as `div`, `a` and `body`.

Slash is enough for elements that consist only of the element itself, such as `img`, `link` and `br`.

Comment: What's a "link"? My understanding is that any tag that has content needs to be closed. Most form elements are an exception. The question I have, which method of closing is an appropriate one?

Comment: @santa Empty elements (void elements) should not be closed at all. Non-empty elements should be closed with an end tag (e.g. `</div>`).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that if you don't use a closing tag, you will be able to set only the tag's attributes.

If you need some content inside it, you need both a opening and a closing tag, having the content in between.

For example, if you need to skip a line using `<br/>`, you could technically also use `<br></br>`, but no one uses it that way, as a line skip will never have anything in between.

In the case of a `<div>`, you will probably have a lot of content inside it, needing a closing tag in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [HTML DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) (4.01 strict, as a 5 dtd is still in progress and has not been released yet), you will see that some elements are defined with an `EMPTY`, meaning these *can* be self closing. Elements that do not have this definition, cannot be self closing.

For example, the `br` element:

```
<!ELEMENT BR - O EMPTY                 -- forced line break -->
```

The `div` element is not defined this way, so it is *never* right to have a self closing `div`.

```
<!ELEMENT DIV - - (%flow;)*            -- generic language/style container -->
```

Comment: Isn't W3C starting to overwrite own rules? Why is there a need to close any elements that do not have any content, like <br>, <hr> etc?

Comment: @santa - HTML is not XML. XHTML _is_ XML. For HTML, you can have `<br>` or `<br />` and they mean the same. For `XHTML`, you can't have `<br>` alone - you must close it. The specs are different as they are based on different (though similar) other specifications.

Comment: So, when you write HTML, why would you worry that it will be interpreted as an XML document?

Comment: @santa - If you write it correctly, and identity it correctly with a `DOCTYPE`, you don't have to worry. Some people are used to XML and since it is much easier to parse XML than HTML, they try to ensure that their HTML is XML compatible, so it can be automated more easily.

Answer (score 0):

If the element is self containing, and has everything that it needs to render itself without any `innerHTML`, than you can use the shorthand `<hr />` otherwise you should use

```
 <div> InnerHTML here </div>
```