# Which HTML tags require a /> at the end?

Tags: html

Example:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Here the tag is closed with `/>`. So, what other tags require a `/>` to close them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closing HTML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261375/closing-html-tag)

Answer (score 1):

The tags which don't need another closing tag are known as **self-closing tags** or **empty elements** or [**void elements**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements). In mark-up languages that use a stricter syntax, such as XHTML we include the slash at the end of the tag to indicate that it is closed.  The list include -

1. `<area />` : Defines clickable area inside a image map
2. `<base />` : Defines specific base path
3. `<br />`   : Defines line breaks
4. `<col />`   : Defines column properties within each column
5. `<embed />` : embeds other elements such as Flash
6. `<hr />`   : Defines a thematic break in HTML page
7. `<img />`  : Used to insert an image
8. `<input />` : Defines input field where user can enter data
9. `<link />` : Defines a link between files
10. `<meta />` : Defines meta data inside the HTML web page
11. `<param />` : Defines passing parameters for an embedded project
12. `<source />` : Defines media resources
13. `<track />` : Specifies text tracks for audio or video elements
14. `<wbr />` : Specifies where in text it's ok to add line-break.

In HTML, there is no rule or requirement to add the `/>` at the end of an empty element. It is allowed in HTML but is not required. However, in stricter syntax language like XML, XHTML, even these elements should be closed. For eg. `<br>` would just work fine in HTML but it needs to be `<br/>` in XML.